# Automatically PULL data and update Excel Sheet with data from new added sheet into excel every month

Tags: excel, vba

Is there any code/VBA/script that i could use to automatically update my master sheet with a newly added sheet into my workbook every month?

Thank you!

I have tried researching online but couldn't find an exact answer/solution to it.

Comment: Welcome to the board.   Could you have a read of [ask] and [mcve] please.  At the moment your question is likely to be closed pretty quickly asking for more information and what you've tried so far.  If you could show what code you've looked at using and exactly what it means to "automatically update my master sheet with a newly added sheet" - update it how?

Comment: What about indirect() and iferror() so if the file does not exist it returns blank?

Answer (score 0):

If you receive your data each month in the same format, you don`t need any programming. Just use Power Query - Excel tool. Once being tuned it will merge new data automatically upon copying new file into chosen folder and refreshing query.